# What's the basis to choose SQL over HQL in hibernate for some queries?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I am using hibernate in my project and I have always used HQL. However, I have seen in other projects where at times SQL queries are used by createSqlQueries, rather than HQL. I wanted to know, what could be the deciding factor to choose SQL over HQL in certain scenarios. Also if there are some queries which can't be performed by HQL and we need to choose only SQL, please cite example.

Comment: I wanted to know atleast one or two issues which cant be achieve by hql. As for example, say we cant perform group by operation through hql. Just an example, didnt mean group by cant be performed. So is there any such concept or query which is not achievable by hibernate? I didnt find direct such answers in google or in stackoverflow. Hence posted!

Answer (score 0):

In `Hibernate`, `HQL` or criteria queries should be able to let you to execute almost any `SQL` query you want. However, many developers are complaint about the Hibernate’s generated `SQL` statement is slow and more prefer to generated their own `SQL` (native SQL) statement.

Comment: Hi,

Pagination is not the limit. I use pagination in my project with hql. the snippet is something like this,

query.setFirstResult(1).setMaxResults(10)

There are certain queries which can't be achieved in hql, and needs to be done through sql. Such scenarios are so very less. Just looking for couple of such instances.

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

-**Performance**. Sometimes is hard to configure Hibernate so it can generate the right sentence when performance is an issue.

-**Using a database propietary feature**. For example, JSON in PostgreSQL.

-**Queries easier to write in SQL**. I once have the requierment to fetch all the data needed for a report in one query. This query joined about ten tables with complex conditions in some cases. The mapping wasn't optimized for that, so it was a lot easier to write the query as a native SQL.

Comment: So there is nothing like unachievable? We can do but things turn out to be complex for scenarios. Nothing like in this and this conditions, we need always to use sql as its not achievable by hql?